Unable to hit POST request on REST based controller using .NET 4.8 framework
Connection controller:
using System.Web.Http;
using eQCsomWebsite.Models;
using eQCsomWebsite.Services;
using eQCsomWebsite.Services.implementer;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace eQCsomWebsite.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/connection")]
    public class ConnectionController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IConnectionService _connectionService;

        // Constructor
        public ConnectionController()
        {
            // Manually resolving dependencies for .NET Framework 4.8 (e.g., via Unity, Ninject, or another DI container)
            _connectionService = new ConnectionService(); // You can use a DI container here
        }

        // POST api/connection/logIn
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("logIn")]
        public IHttpActionResult LogIn([FromBody] LogInRequest request)
        {
            if (request == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Password))
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid login parameters.");
            }

            var response = _connectionService.LogIn(request);

            if (response == null || !response.Success)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(response);
        }

        // POST api/connection/logOff
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("logOff")]
        public IHttpActionResult LogOff([FromBody] LogOffRequest request)
        {
            if (request == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Token))
            {
                return BadRequest("Token is required for logout.");
            }

            var response = _connectionService.LogOff(request);

            if (response == null || !response.Success)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
}

Global.asax.cs:
using Unity;
using Unity.WebApi;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using eQCsomWebsite.Services;
using eQCsomWebsite.Services.implementer;

namespace eQCsomWebsite
{
    public class CsomApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // Initialize Unity container
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // Register dependencies
            container.RegisterType<IConnectionService, ConnectionService>();
            container.RegisterType<IMetadataService, MetadataService>();
            container.RegisterType<IOperationService, OperationService>();

            // Set Web API Dependency Resolver to Unity
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

            // Register Web API configuration
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

            // Register MVC routes (if using MVC)
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}

RouteConfig.cs:
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace eQCsomWebsite
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            // Ignore routes for certain file types
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            // Add MVC routing (for normal MVC controllers)
            // routes.MapRoute(
            //     name: "Default",
            //     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            //     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            // );

            // Add Web API routing
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        }
    }
}

<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

   <system.webServer>
    <!-- Registering Web API Handler -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="WebApiHandler" path="api/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler, System.Web.Http.WebHost" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>

    <!-- Registering Web API Module -->
    <modules>
      <add name="WebApiModule" type="System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpModule, System.Web.Http.WebHost" />
    </modules>

    <!-- URL Rewrite for Web API routing -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="WebAPI Routing">
          <match url="^api/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/api/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

  <!-- Optional: Configuration for HTTP request logging and diagnostics -->
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Web" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="WebApiDiagnostics" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>

This API is not working. I start the server in VS Code and using IIS, but I'm not able to hit endpoint.
WebApiConfig.cs:
using System.Web.Http;

namespace eQCsomWebsite
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API route configuration
            // Use attribute routing (this will automatically use [Route] and [RoutePrefix] attributes in controllers)
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Optional: You can also define a default route pattern if needed
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

I am not able to hit this POST method for login or logout using Postman
Url: http://localhost:32578/api/connection/logIn
In authentication tab, I have selected basic auth.

Pretty sure the attribute route [Route("logIn")] would be resolving as "http://localhost:32578/login". If you want the API/Controller in the route, add that to the attribute ([Route("api/connection/logIn")]) or re-enable the default routing rule and just use the RouteAttribute for alternate/special routes.

Nothing particularly jumps out. Please edit the post by removing enough of all of that code so that we're left with a minimal, reproducible example.

Have you looked at the order of the attributes that you are using?   I use ASP Netcore and not .NET 4.8, but the order of attributes makes a difference for me.  In ASP Netcore 2.2 the attributes are ordered as [Route] first, then [Authorize], then [Http] last.  Also, if this is an Api Controller in which the route attribute identifies the endpoint, can you have an [HttpPost] attribute for a method that is not named "Post( ....  )"?
